# How to parse json object containing json array in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

i've build an API for myself to return some data , this data is returned in json form like that

```
{
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
    }
]}
```

the problem is that i can't accesss any field of this data , i've been trying it on REST client by these inputs

```
{
"test" : {
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
    }
]}}
```

the "test" is the name of the input passed from the android to the API.

when i make a request like the above i get nothing , but when doing something like

```
{
"test" : 
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
    }
]}
```

handling it with this code

```
$test = $request->input('test');
    $final_Length_Array = array('list', $test);
    $var = $final_Length_Array[1][0]['name'];

    return response()->json([
        'state' => '1',

        'test' => $var
    ]);
```

i get me desired value , now if any one can tell me how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not a valid JSON** value:

```
{
  "test" : {
    [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "year": "1st",
        "curriculum": "Arts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The value of the **test** key is an object and it should contain **key-value** pairs, not a list.

In the future you can use the online validator to check, if given string is a JSON value, e.g. https://jsonlint.com/. Please also have a look at the JSON specification a thttp://www.json.org/ to see what it should look like.